# PHP Not calculating correct date

Tags: php, datetime, datetime-format

I have this code, and it's not returning the images correctly, at a certain time of day I need an image to change. However, the code isn't putting the right image in, the cover works, have I done the date and time wrong?

```
<?php

// H = hour
// i = minute
// n = day of the week

$dj = 'cover';
if(date("Hin", time()) == '06001'){ $dj = 'test1'; }
elseif(date("Hin", time()) == '06002'){ $dj = 'test1'; }
elseif(date("Hin", time()) == '14006'){ $dj = 'test3'; }

// 06001 = Monday at 06:00
// 06002 = Tuesday at 06:00
// 14006 = Saturday at 13:00

?>

<img class="cover" src="img/djs/<?php echo $dj; ?>.png" alt="DJ <?php echo $dj; ?>" />
```

Comment: is it actually what you want, that, test1, test2 and test3 are displayed *exactly* at the given time, meaning 06:00, but not 06:01? because that's what the code is doing

Comment: Franz - The issue was I didn't do a capital "N" and yeah that was also an issue, I removed the minutes in the end so the images display hourly otherwise it was expecting an image every minute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`n` is not day of the week. it's a numeric representation of a month, without leading zeros (1 to 12)

I think this is your problem.

If you want day of the week, you have to use capital `N`.

So your code would be like:

```
<?php

// H = hour
// i = minute
// N = day of the week

$dj = 'cover';
if(date("HiN", time()) == '06001'){ $dj = 'test1'; }
elseif(date("HiN", time()) == '06002'){ $dj = 'test1'; }
elseif(date("HiN", time()) == '14006'){ $dj = 'test3'; }

// 06001 = Monday at 06:00
// 06002 = Tuesday at 06:00
// 14006 = Saturday at 13:00

?>

<img class="cover" src="img/djs/<?php echo $dj; ?>.png" alt="DJ <?php echo $dj; ?>" />
```

Comment: Unfortunately it was me being a prat, it was the capital N haha! Thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are trying to do is show the image for the duration between those times. If this is the case, then try the following:

```
<?php
$dj = 'cover';
$day = date("N", time());
$time = (date("H") * 60) + date("i"); // current time in minutes
switch($day) {
    case 1: // Monday
        if($time >= 360) {
            $dj = 'test1';
        }
        break;
    case 2: // Tuesday
        if($time >= 360) {
            $dj = 'test1';
        }
        break;
    case 6: // Saturday
        if($time >= 840) {
            $dj = 'test3';
        }
        break;
}
echo sprintf('<img class="cover" src="img/djs/%s.png" alt="DJ %s" />', $dj, $dj);
```

In this example, the image will be displayed as 'cover' after every day at midnight, but will display 'test1' etc, after the proposed periods.  The condition `$time > 360`, etc, are based on the minutes from the start of the day, so 360 is 6 AM.

Since (in the example you supplied), you wish to show 'test' on both Monday and Tuesday starting at 6 am, you can simplify the code by allowing the `case` to fall through and run the same code for both scenarios as follows :

```
<?php
$dj = 'cover';
$day = date("N", time());
$time = (date("H") * 60) + date("i"); // current time in minutes
switch($day) {
    case 1: // Monday
    case 2: // Tuesday
        if($time >= 360) {
            $dj = 'test1';
        }
        break;
    case 6: // Saturday
        if($time >= 840) {
            $dj = 'test3';
        }
        break;
}
echo sprintf('<img class="cover" src="img/djs/%s.png" alt="DJ %s" />', $dj, $dj);
```

Comment: Hey, this is a bit advanced for what I'm doing as there would be thousands of lines of code haha! Thanks though.